# How To identify which Div is displaying the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, dom, devtools

My dashboard app is a single page - never longer than 100vh.

In a certain place, when I click a button, some unknown container temporarily overflows and a scrollbar appears on the right side, and then one second later it disappears. During that one second, the page background jumps very noticeably.

I wish to prevent this scrollbar from displaying via CSS - but I am having difficulty identifying the container that is overflowing.

Does anyone know of a method or a trick to identify which div is displaying the scrollbar right now, or which div has overflowed the screen?  I've been at this for a while and thinking, there's got to be a DevTools trick for quickly finding this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens during an action I would ask myself which are the DOM elements that are loaded at this moment and I would probably try to add something like `overflow: hidden;` on the elements loaded at this moment to see which one Do it.

If there is javascript, breakpoints can be useful.

It is also possible to put some on the DOM (element inspector, right click on a div or other elements then "break on" and "subtree modification" for example)

[image]

I find the breakpoint very practical to go back to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I used Hadock's answer to solve my problem. Using the Break On Subtree Modifications (BOSM for short), I was able to do the following:

1. I set BOSM on a div that I thought was just above where things were being added, and re-ran the app.
2. The app paused with the scrollbar displayed - exactly what I wanted.
3. In DevTools console, I entered the following:

   **`[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(x => x.scrollHeight > 1000)`**

   this returned all Divs with big scrollbars (height > 1000px). In my case, they were:

   - html
   - body
   - #react-entry-point
4. I was able to add the css:

   `#react-entry-point{overflow: hidden;}`

and my problem is resolved.

This might not be a good solution for everyone, but for me, with my 100vh (max) one-page application, it did the trick.

---

**Here are some other useful (related) console commands:**

*Display all containers that might have a scrollbar displayed (courtesy of user [A1rPun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449624/a1rpun)):*

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(x => x.clientHeight < x.scrollHeight)
```

*Display all containers with a scrollbar > 150px:*

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('*')].filter(x => x.scrollHeight > 150)
```